# Segmentation fault in Django with matplotlib

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, matplotlib

I am getting segmentation fault in Django, when using matlplot lib to generate the graphs dynamically in the same.

Here is the stack trace:

```
Process:         Python [97865]
Path:            /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Identifier:      Python
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  bash [319]

Date/Time:       2013-09-01 14:26:07.510 +0530
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.7.5 (11G63)
Report Version:  9

Anonymous UUID:                      3775C51A-D45F-4F98-847D-12C386DC42C2

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
objc[97865]: garbage collection is OFF

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8786782a __kill + 10
1   org.python.python               0x00000001001081bb posix_kill + 59
2   org.python.python               0x00000001000c1e7d PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 25213
3   org.python.python               0x00000001000c286d PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 27757
4   org.python.python               0x00000001000c4149 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2137
5   org.python.python               0x00000001000c1a3d PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 24125
6   org.python.python               0x00000001000c4149 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2137
7   org.python.python               0x000000010003d910 function_call + 176
8   org.python.python               0x000000010000c362 PyObject_Call + 98
9   org.python.python               0x00000001000bcebd PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 4797
10  org.python.python               0x00000001000c4149 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2137
11  org.python.python               0x000000010003d910 function_call + 176
12  org.python.python               0x000000010000c362 PyObject_Call + 98
13  org.python.python               0x00000001000bcebd PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 4797
14  org.python.python               0x00000001000c4149 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2137
15  org.python.python               0x000000010003d910 function_call + 176
16  org.python.python               0x000000010000c362 PyObject_Call + 98
17  org.python.python               0x00000001000bcebd PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 4797
18  org.python.python               0x00000001000c4149 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2137
19  org.python.python               0x00000001000c1a3d PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 24125
20  org.python.python               0x00000001000c286d PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 27757
21  org.python.python               0x00000001000c4149 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2137
22  org.python.python               0x00000001000c1a3d PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 24125
23  org.python.python               0x00000001000c4149 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2137
24  org.python.python               0x00000001000c4266 PyEval_EvalCode + 54
25  org.python.python               0x00000001000e8ede PyRun_FileExFlags + 174
26  org.python.python               0x00000001000e9199 PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 489
27  org.python.python               0x000000010010006d Py_Main + 3085
28  org.python.python               0x0000000100000f14 0x100000000 + 3860

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x000000010019e778  rcx: 0x00007fff5fbfd718  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000000017e49  rsi: 0x000000000000000b  rbp: 0x00007fff5fbfd730  rsp: 0x00007fff5fbfd718
   r8: 0x00007fff742fd0b0   r9: 0x0000000000000100  r10: 0x0000000000000000  r11: 0xffffff80002dad60
  r12: 0x000000010030a220  r13: 0x00000001002c67e8  r14: 0x0000000101938b30  r15: 0x00000001018b8170
  rip: 0x00007fff8786782a  rfl: 0x0000000000000206  cr2: 0x000000010016e4a0
Logical CPU: 0

Binary Images:
       0x100000000 -        0x100000fff +org.python.python (2.7.3 - 2.7.3) <BE41DDF4-595E-0D6D-89DB-413749B339C3> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
       0x100003000 -        0x10016dff7 +org.python.python (2.7.3, [c] 2004-2012 Python Software Foundation. - 2.7.3) <4F9EF48A-7D0C-0C1A-670B-3BF4E72C8696> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python
       0x1002ef000 -        0x1002f3fff +_collections.so (??? - ???) <9D150F88-A639-8D17-B4C1-B003ED64A825> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_collections.so
       0x1002f9000 -        0x1002f9fff +_bisect.so (??? - ???) <7C2E4AE4-BD2E-E0B1-ED49-C97797A87862> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_bisect.so
       0x1002fc000 -        0x1002fdff7 +_functools.so (??? - ???) <C721B452-8187-D7D2-00A6-216C47F4BDA8> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_functools.so
       0x1004de000 -        0x1004e2ff7 +operator.so (??? - ???) <BCE61645-883B-69E4-325D-67E5158E52F1> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/operator.so
       0x1004e9000 -        0x1004f0ff7 +itertools.so (??? - ???) <A54988DB-048C-C726-752F-754ABD6386DA> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/itertools.so
       0x1004fb000 -        0x1004fcff7 +_heapq.so (??? - ???) <6E943E3D-86B8-E5B6-6469-4F37AB67DD0F> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_heapq.so
       0x100640000 -        0x100643ff7 +strop.so (??? - ???) <6389C456-82E5-D58F-D87D-78445284CDEC> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/strop.so
       0x100688000 -        0x10068afff +_locale.so (??? - ???) <8410BA87-ECC3-40D3-6540-25F3954A791B> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_locale.so
       0x10068e000 -        0x100692fff +_struct.so (??? - ???) <F9707FF4-712E-9991-DF85-0C46C199B551> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_struct.so
       0x1006d9000 -        0x1006e1fff +_socket.so (??? - ???) <4B24FFF5-0303-2D87-BFB1-20A45E087B69> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_socket.so
       0x1006eb000 -        0x1006efff7 +_ssl.so (??? - ???) <51E5DA69-DE4B-7883-0F68-3AAD95D277B0> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ssl.so
       0x1006f5000 -        0x1006f6fff +cStringIO.so (??? - ???) <C0567EB0-1EC7-2285-7272-FDC80AB554F6> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/cStringIO.so
       0x1006fb000 -        0x1006fdfff +time.so (??? - ???) <92709D00-9460-B5B6-B97F-100C3A055DBB> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/time.so
       0x100703000 -        0x100706fef +binascii.so (??? - ???) <1D3A5AFB-4FDE-4B1D-7BAB-ED2E8B4DC3BF> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/binascii.so
       0x10074a000 -        0x10074afff +_scproxy.so (??? - ???) <CCC0A4C1-2AF9-695D-2343-6E12AB46029C> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_scproxy.so
       0x10074d000 -        0x10075bfff +datetime.so (??? - ???) <727CB885-962A-A1E6-CDEF-8F113BB97998> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/datetime.so
       0x100794000 -        0x100799fef +math.so (??? - ???) <72277351-515A-6D6A-556C-B863114DB023> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/math.so
       0x1007e0000 -        0x1007e1fff +_hashlib.so (??? - ???) <FD6A5D40-49F8-B2BD-46B3-C88326DF323B> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_hashlib.so
       0x1007e5000 -        0x1007e6fff +_random.so (??? - ???) <959FCA12-F992-BD11-053D-4FA2E312ECBB> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_random.so
       0x1007e9000 -        0x1007f8ff7 +cPickle.so (??? - ???) <2F2B7AB6-CB55-1343-A766-831844DEBF4C> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/cPickle.so
       0x101280000 -        0x101283ff7 +zlib.so (??? - ???) <5FCCA2F5-5905-5742-7654-2F56C4876630> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/zlib.so
       0x101288000 -        0x10128dfff +_speedups.so (??? - ???) <D72A568A-55B8-3B94-A863-C2311CAF07F0> /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/simplejson/_speedups.so
       0x101292000 -        0x101297fff +array.so (??? - ???) <DE53EB92-8A7F-177A-E308-661DF4581E12> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/array.so
       0x10135e000 -        0x10135fff7 +fcntl.so (??? - ???) <888D3D1A-9537-E266-ED0B-0626C1965FE5> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/fcntl.so
       0x1013a2000 -        0x101436fef +unicodedata.so (??? - ???) <E5D27CFB-8553-A099-04CE-B1656A66DBB0> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/unicodedata.so
       0x10144d000 -        0x101462fff +_io.so (??? - ???) <0F55095A-E667-67A1-8C82-F52FE6FD4B55> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
       0x1014f9000 -        0x1014f9fff +grp.so (??? - ???) <B6D0F708-FE26-7A12-DCFF-0FCFF1CCE1A1> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/grp.so
       0x101740000 -        0x101774fff +pyexpat.so (??? - ???) <BFB8AAA0-08D8-1FAC-54CA-F996DEFEE0F9> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/pyexpat.so
       0x101846000 -        0x101849fff +select.so (??? - ???) <4FAF1D70-ED6A-D278-4025-017E5690DD7A> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/select.so
       0x1018cf000 -        0x1018d0fff +termios.so (??? - ???) <C0B8887B-F4E0-3ADE-B380-0298F04028CC> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/termios.so
    0x7fff69957000 -     0x7fff6998bbaf  dyld (195.6 - ???) <C58DAD8A-4B00-3676-8637-93D6FDE73147> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7fff82f8e000 -     0x7fff82f94ff7  libunwind.dylib (30.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <1E9C6C8C-CBE8-3F4B-A5B5-E03E3AB53231> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
    0x7fff83114000 -     0x7fff8311cfff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib (??? - ???) <584B321E-5159-37CD-B2E7-82E069C70AFB> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
    0x7fff832ca000 -     0x7fff832cbfff  libdnsinfo.dylib (395.11.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <853BAAA5-270F-3FDC-B025-D448DB72E1C3> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
    0x7fff83355000 -     0x7fff83529ff7  com.apple.CoreFoundation (6.7.2 - 635.21) <62A3402E-A4E7-391F-AD20-1EF20236CE1B> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
    0x7fff83664000 -     0x7fff83866fff  libicucore.A.dylib (46.1.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <0176782F-9526-3905-813A-7A5676EC2C86> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
    0x7fff8386c000 -     0x7fff8386efff  com.apple.TrustEvaluationAgent (2.0 - 1) <1F31CAFF-C1C6-33D3-94E9-11B721761DDF> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TrustEvaluationAgent.framework/Versions/A/TrustEvaluationAgent
    0x7fff8386f000 -     0x7fff8388cfff  libxpc.dylib (77.19.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <9F57891B-D7EF-3050-BEDD-21E7C6668248> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
    0x7fff83c86000 -     0x7fff83c8dfff  libcopyfile.dylib (85.1.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <0AB51EE2-E914-358C-AC19-47BC024BDAE7> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
    0x7fff842f4000 -     0x7fff84336ff7  libcommonCrypto.dylib (55010.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <BB770C22-8C57-365A-8716-4A3C36AE7BFB> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
    0x7fff84ddb000 -     0x7fff84de5ff7  liblaunch.dylib (392.39.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <8C235D13-2928-30E5-9E12-2CC3D6324AE2> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
    0x7fff84e49000 -     0x7fff84e4ffff  libmacho.dylib (800.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <165514D7-1BFA-38EF-A151-676DCD21FB64> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
    0x7fff84e50000 -     0x7fff84e5bff7  libc++abi.dylib (14.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <8FF3D766-D678-36F6-84AC-423C878E6D14> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
    0x7fff854d0000 -     0x7fff854d1ff7  libsystem_blocks.dylib (53.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <8BCA214A-8992-34B2-A8B9-B74DEACA1869> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
    0x7fff8635b000 -     0x7fff86388fe7  libSystem.B.dylib (159.1.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <6E5C8AC3-DBB7-31CB-BEB7-D6ED8E6DE0CE> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
    0x7fff866bb000 -     0x7fff866bcfff  libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib (??? - ???) <3DCF577B-F126-302B-BCE2-4DB9A95B8598> /usr/lib/libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib
    0x7fff868d3000 -     0x7fff8690cfe7  libssl.0.9.8.dylib (44.0.0 - compatibility 0.9.8) <79AAEC98-1258-3DA4-B1C0-4120049D390B> /usr/lib/libssl.0.9.8.dylib
    0x7fff86997000 -     0x7fff869a9ff7  libz.1.dylib (1.2.5 - compatibility 1.0.0) <30CBEF15-4978-3DED-8629-7109880A19D4> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
    0x7fff86aa5000 -     0x7fff86aa9fff  libdyld.dylib (195.6.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <FFC59565-64BD-3B37-90A4-E2C3A422CFC1> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
    0x7fff87851000 -     0x7fff87871fff  libsystem_kernel.dylib (1699.32.7 - compatibility 1.0.0) <66C9F9BD-C7B3-30D4-B1A0-03C8A6392351> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
    0x7fff87b01000 -     0x7fff87b03fff  libquarantine.dylib (36.7.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <8D9832F9-E4A9-38C3-B880-E5210B2353C7> /usr/lib/system/libquarantine.dylib
    0x7fff87b04000 -     0x7fff87b08fff  libmathCommon.A.dylib (2026.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <FF83AFF7-42B2-306E-90AF-D539C51A4542> /usr/lib/system/libmathCommon.A.dylib
    0x7fff87b66000 -     0x7fff87ba1fff  libsystem_info.dylib (??? - ???) <35F90252-2AE1-32C5-8D34-782C614D9639> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
    0x7fff87f07000 -     0x7fff88013fff  libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib (44.0.0 - compatibility 0.9.8) <3A8E1F89-5E26-3C8B-B538-81F5D61DBF8A> /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib
    0x7fff8921b000 -     0x7fff8921cfff  libunc.dylib (24.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <337960EE-0A85-3DD0-A760-7134CF4C0AFF> /usr/lib/system/libunc.dylib
    0x7fff8921d000 -     0x7fff8921eff7  libremovefile.dylib (21.1.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <739E6C83-AA52-3C6C-A680-B37FE2888A04> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
    0x7fff89288000 -     0x7fff892d6fff  libauto.dylib (??? - ???) <D8AC8458-DDD0-3939-8B96-B6CED81613EF> /usr/lib/libauto.dylib
    0x7fff893e0000 -     0x7fff893e1ff7  libsystem_sandbox.dylib (??? - ???) <5422BA4A-4C96-3BC1-AF83-14F0CED0ECB5> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
    0x7fff8a347000 -     0x7fff8a42be5f  libobjc.A.dylib (228.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <871E688B-CF57-3BC7-80D6-F6476DFF109B> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
    0x7fff8ac5e000 -     0x7fff8ac63fff  libcache.dylib (47.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <1571C3AB-BCB2-38CD-B3B2-C5FC3F927C6A> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
    0x7fff8bbba000 -     0x7fff8bc97fef  libsystem_c.dylib (763.13.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <41B43515-2806-3FBC-ACF1-A16F35B7E290> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
    0x7fff8dc51000 -     0x7fff8dc51fff  libkeymgr.dylib (23.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <61EFED6A-A407-301E-B454-CD18314F0075> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
    0x7fff8e072000 -     0x7fff8e07bff7  libsystem_notify.dylib (80.1.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <A4D651E3-D1C6-3934-AD49-7A104FD14596> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
    0x7fff8e2eb000 -     0x7fff8e337ff7  com.apple.SystemConfiguration (1.11.3 - 1.11) <131780ED-E8DD-3153-81F2-5FEC4F6554C2> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/Versions/A/SystemConfiguration
    0x7fff8e338000 -     0x7fff8e33dff7  libsystem_network.dylib (??? - ???) <5DE7024E-1D2D-34A2-80F4-08326331A75B> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
    0x7fff8e349000 -     0x7fff8e3bfff7  libc++.1.dylib (28.4.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <A24FC3DA-4FFA-3DD2-9DCC-2B8D1B3BF97C> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
    0x7fff8ef0f000 -     0x7fff8ef82fff  libstdc++.6.dylib (52.0.0 - compatibility 7.0.0) <6BDD43E4-A4B1-379E-9ED5-8C713653DFF2> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
    0x7fff8f4ae000 -     0x7fff8f4bcfff  libdispatch.dylib (187.10.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <8E03C652-922A-3399-93DE-9EA0CBFA0039> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
    0x7fff8f94d000 -     0x7fff8f952fff  libcompiler_rt.dylib (6.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <98ECD5F6-E85C-32A5-98CD-8911230CB66A> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 1
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 990542
    thread_create: 1501
    thread_set_state: 1544

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=62.9M resident=75.5M(120%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=16777216.0T(27990054404096%)
Writable regions: Total=29.9M written=4380K(14%) resident=13.8M(46%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=16.1M(54%)

REGION TYPE                      VIRTUAL
===========                      =======
MALLOC                             21.5M
MALLOC guard page                    32K
STACK GUARD                        56.0M
Stack                              8192K
VM_ALLOCATE                           4K
__DATA                             1976K
__LINKEDIT                         49.9M
__TEXT                             13.0M
__UNICODE                           544K
shared memory                        12K
===========                      =======
TOTAL                             150.8M

Model: MacBookPro8,2, BootROM MBP81.0047.B27, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.2 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 1.69f3
Graphics: AMD Radeon HD 6750M, AMD Radeon HD 6750M, PCIe, 512 MB
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 3000, Intel HD Graphics 3000, Built-In, 512 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x014F, 0x4A4D313333334B534E2D3447202020202020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x014F, 0x4A4D313333334B534E2D3447202020202020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xD6), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.198.19.22)
Bluetooth: Version 4.0.8f17, 2 service, 11 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Ethernet, Ethernet, en0
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: TOSHIBA MK5065GSXF, 500.11 GB
Serial ATA Device: MATSHITADVD-R   UJ-8A8
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in), apple_vendor_id, 0x8509, 0xfa200000 / 3
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2513, 0xfa100000 / 2
USB Device: BRCM2070 Hub, 0x0a5c  (Broadcom Corp.), 0x4500, 0xfa110000 / 5
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller, apple_vendor_id, 0x821a, 0xfa113000 / 8
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad, apple_vendor_id, 0x0252, 0xfa120000 / 4
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2513, 0xfd100000 / 2
USB Device: IR Receiver, apple_vendor_id, 0x8242, 0xfd110000 / 3
```

Any suggestions to debug this and fix this would be appreciated.

Thanks